# Spring Thymeleaf for each last not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am Iterating over mongodb document by below code.

```
<tr th:each="document, state : ${data}">
            <td th:text="${state.last}"></td>
</tr>
```

I got below Exception.

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: 
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "state.last"
```

Comment: The iteration status has a last (boolean-)property. Thus, I think the problem is somewhere else. Maybe your mongodb-object isn't ittarable. Have a look at the corresponing list: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#iterable-values

Answer (score 0):

In base of the [guide](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status), I suggest you to invert state and document, same this:

```
<tr th:each="state,document : ${data}">
            <td th:text="${state.last}"></td>
</tr>
```

If `document` is a status variable defined in the `th:each` attribute. 
Otherwise, try to provide more information about the object you are going through

Comment: no thats not correct status variable must be defined after iteration variable and document is mongodb Document.

Comment: Definitly not correct. 'last' is a is property of the iteration status and the optional status variable has to be placed after the iteration variable.

Comment: so any help? why last not working while first, count , index are working fine